# URL of a file in WebContent folder of an XPages project

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, font-awesome, lotus

I want to import font awesome in xpages. I have found that importing files in Webcontent folder makes them accessible from xpages but i cannot find the url to refer to them.

Now i have the whole folder of font awesome under WebContent folder and i want to import as a resource to the xpage the stylesheet file: WebContent/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css

i am using this code

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:styleSheet href="WebContent/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css"></xp:styleSheet>
</xp:this.resources>
```

and i have tried many different url in href attribute.

What is the correct url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the correct location. The url should be without WebContent/.